TypeScript definition for a JSON object based on other entry in the JSON object
I have a JSON object I'm writing a TypeScript definition for. In this object I would like to enumerate the components. At this time the components property is an array of strings. It's unrestricted but I would like to add an overrides property where entries from the components array can have prop overrides specified.
Is there a way to restrict the componentName key in the overrides object to match one of the entries in the components array? Currently I have it set like this:
interface MyJsonObject {
    components: string[];
    overrides: {
        [componentName: string]: {
             [propName: string]: unknown;
        };
    };
}

But I would like to validate that this is valid:
const config: MyJsonObject = {
    components: ['test'],
    overrides: {
        test: {
            foo: 'bar',
        }
    }
}

And that this is invalid
const config: MyJsonObject = {
    components: ['test'],
    overrides: {
        baz: {
            foo: 'bar',
        }
    }
}


Yes, you can use generics:
type MyJsonObject<TKey extends string> = {
    components: TKey[];
    /* If overrides are optional for each component, you can wrap the outer record
       in Partial<> */
    overrides: Record<TKey, Record<string, unknown>>;
}

const config: MyJsonObject<'test'> = {
    components: ['test'],
    overrides: {
        baz: {
            foo: 'bar',
        }
    }
}

But this is a bit clunky, since you have to specify the type of TKey. We can use a function to help us infer the type:
type MyJsonObject<TKey extends string> = {
    components: TKey[];
    overrides: Record<TKey, Record<string, unknown>>;
}

function validateStructure<TKey extends string>(myThing: MyJsonObject<TKey>): MyJsonObject<TKey> {
    return myThing;
}

const configA = validateStructure({
    components: ['test'],
    overrides: {
        test: {
            foo: 'bar',
        }
    }
});

const configB = validateStructure({
    components: ['test'],
    overrides: {
        /* Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'baz' does not exist in type 
           'Record<"test", Record<string, unknown>>' */
        baz: {
            foo: 'bar',
        }
    }
});

There is an open issue to be able to do so without the use of a function just to infer the generic parameter.

Awesome! And yes I was hoping to be able to infer the generic parameter so the consumer won't need to specify parameters but this will do for now. Thanks!
